# Printing fibonacci series in recursion

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

I am trying to print Fibonacci series using recursion and my code is not ending the recursion . Can you tell me if i missed something.I think the second recursion is going into infinite loop and i am not able to figure out why it is happening

```
class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
      int k=7;
      int x=0,y=1;
      fib(x,y,k,0);
      return;

  }

  public static void fib(int x,int y,int k,int cnt)
  {
      int z;
      if(cnt>k)
      return;

      if(cnt<=k)
      {
          z=x+y;
          x=y;
          y=z;
          System.out.println("value is"+z);

          fib(x,y,k,cnt++);

      }

  }
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to learn recursion then you should consider the approach Imran outlined below. The solution you have, while technically recursive, is not really the "natural" recursive solution (it's "tail-recursive" and so changing it to a non-recursive for loop is trivial). The idea behind Imran's solution is that the (common) definition of a Fibonacci number is itself recursive (it uses Fibonacci numbers in the definition!). A natural recursive solution would take advantage of that. Hence `fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)` is the definition... and also the (pseudo-)code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the *post*-increment in:

```
  fib(x,y,k,cnt++);
```

This passes the original value of `cnt` to the recursive call, and *then* increments it.

If you print the value of `cnt` at the start of `fib()`, you'll see that it is always zero.

One easy fix is to change that call to

```
  fib(x,y,k,cnt+1);
```

Also, your numbering of Fibonacci numbers is a bit odd (I'd say that the seventh number is 8 and your code thinks it's 34).

Finally, I may be worth noting that the second `if` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to understand the concept of Fibonacci Number. Please read the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). Following is the code for this function.

```
public static int fib(int n)
{
    if(n == 0 || n == 1)
        return n;

    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

Comment: You can print the numbers before the last line in the function to print the series.

Comment: I disagree with the above comment

Comment: @Imran S Shouldn't this be return 1 instead of return n?